# Control youtube's Overlay with api

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

i made a script to upload videos to youtube from a folder on my server, but now i want a way to control the overlay ads. i saw a video that has just like what i want.
here is the video link:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_v0JoEarI8s

is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the Call-to-Action overlays can not be managed from the API

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/wyUoI9S2c0M

Apparently can only be configured manually

http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150471